# How can I identify Xpaths using Class and HTML Tag Position

Tags: selenium, xpath, selenium-ide

I am new to `selenium ide`. Trying to get the 2nd html tag with class with same value.

```
<div class="test">
<div>
<small class="jo-date-time text-muted">Ordered on Jun 23, 2016 </small>
</div>
</div>
<div class="test">
<div>
<small class="jo-date-time text-muted">Ordered on Jun 22, 2016 </small>
</div>
</div>
```

e.g.
`class=jo-date-time[2] and //small[@class='jo-date-time'][2]`

But, it doesn't work. It still needs the parent html tag. Is it really like that?

This one works for me. -> `//div[@class='test'][2]/div/small`

Answer (score 0):

Those xpaths were not working because they are incorrect.

If you notice the `class` attribute, there is a space and then again text which you omitted. That is the reason it is not working.

**Change from :**
`//small[@class='jo-date-time'][2]`

**To :** `(//small[@class='jo-date-time text-muted'])[2]`

[image]

And I personally do not use index as that may vary if there is way to avoid.

Here is another way avoiding the use of index:
`//small[@class='jo-date-time text-muted' and . = 'Ordered on Jun 22, 2016 ']`

Comment: I tried using (//small[@class='jo-date-time text-muted'])[2] although it still doesn't work.The reason I'm using index is because the data are dynamic and may change. I just want to check if they are present.

By the way, should it really be enclosed with ()?

Comment: @LovieT, do you want to provide more details? How you are using it ? What I provided is a tested result

Answer (score 0):

If the element is to be located by class name **jo-date-time**

Then try **contains** function in xpath

```
//small[contains(@class,'jo-date-time')][2]
```